# Survey: reading answers before voting

Tags: discussion

Motivated by these questions:

[Case Study: First Answer Bias](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414/19607) and [Are upvotes skewed towards the first answer to a question?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3826/19607)

I propose a biased (biased towards people who use the meta site) study of AcademiaSE users to see how much of an upvote biases the first answer to a question gets (the "fastest gun in the west" problem) from "non-random" Academia users.  To wit,

> For questions you read which have multiple answers, do you typically vote on an answer before reading other answers? (Answer by up-voting answers below.  At least for this question, please read the answers first and upvote at least one.)

Comment: There are several other effects that may generate bias. For instance, I frequently skip very long answers because I don't have enough time to read them. I may later get back to a few of the skipped answers if I know that the writer is someone whose style and ideas I like. I also seldom read long streams of answers, when there are 5 or more, or I read them selectively. Or I seldom read late additions. Again, I don't have enough time to read everything.

Answer (score 11):

I typically vote on answers I like right after reading them but usually read several of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I typically read most answers before voting.

Answer (score 1):

**Other** (vote before reading, never vote, ...)

Please explain in comments.

Comment: I upvote multiple answers if appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

I typically vote on answers I like right after reading them and often don't read further answers.